# Google Analytics usage and GDPR

Tags: google-analytics, shiny

I have recently created and made an R Shiny app to present data my group is publishing with a paper. The app contains Google analytics tracker, only for the purposed of seeing the number of viewers (so far there haven't been any), and where those viewers are from. I am just wondering now if the use of GA for this purposes is GDPR compliant and if it does require consent from anyone visiting the website? I couldn't find a clear answer to this, so any advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Any updates on this in the year 2021?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a legal question, and not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

In general, GDPR does not prevent you doing anything as such. Whatever you do with Personal Data, you must have a legal basis for each purpose (see Article 6 of the GDPR)

You may want to look at current ePrivacy directive (Directive 2002/58/EC) and especially the upcoming ePrivacy Regulation (probably will be applicable in 2020).

The ePrivacy directive, specifically Article 5(3), requires prior informed consent for storage or for access to information stored on a user's terminal equipment. In other words, you must ask users if they agree to most cookies and similar technologies (e.g. web beacons, Flash cookies, etc.) before your site starts to use them. There are some exceptins to this, however I'm afraid Google Analytics is not considered as 'strictly necessary' in the sense.

From the GDPR point of view, the problems arise as there are other processing activities than just counting the number of viewers. Last time I checked the GA agreement, Google wants to use that data for their own purposes as well. Disclosing that data to Google can be done with your visitors' consent, however as consent must be informed and 'freely given' (see Article 7 of the GDPR), I don't think any user would actually give their consent if it's not mandatory for them (if it's mandatory to access the service, consent is not 'freely given').

This is one of the reasons why we at PrivacyAnt use only matomo (piwik) on our public website as we have full control over the data.

Could write a book about this topic as it's quite complex but hopefully my answer makes some sense!

Comment: Glad this answer didn't wasn't approved since it really didn't answer the question. Currently, it's a mess from both the developer perspective and the EU's, who apparently aren't policing GDPR. Regarding Google Analytics, Google now claims a fair amount of support for GDPR and the OP should check it out: https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy - personally I would recommend (assuming it's commercially feasible) to block distribution of apps to EU regions until the requirements on small-time developers become more clear.